# Why is maximum number of joints of 6 lines is 4?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

The following is considered in Lary Guth's Polynomial Methods in Combinatorics, page 14.
Let $L$ be a set of lines in $\mathbb R^3$. A point $x$ which lies in some set of three non-co-planar lines of $L$ is called a joint of $L$. Suppose $L$ has $6$ lines. Then, why is it that $L$ has at most $4$ joints?

This has been my approach so far:

1. Note that the tetrahedron has 6 edges and 4 vertices. If we take our $L$ to be the set of 6 lines containing each of the six edges of a tetrahedron, we get that each of its vertex is a joint as the three lines intersecting any vertex are non-co-planar.
2. Now, I want to argue that if one wants to maximize the number of joints possible for any set of six lines, the configuration of a tetrahedron is the best possible one.

The problem is that I don't know why or how to prove 3.
Any suggestions will be really helpful :)

Comment: I think your use of the qualifier *any* in the definition is misleading. A point is called a joint if it lies in *some* set of three non-coplanar lines in $L$

Comment: Oh yes indeed, thanks. I have changed this in the question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph, and we're interested in the vertices which fulfill $deg(v) \geq 3$. We notice that $|E| = 6$ from the assignment, and we can use your earlier fact that a tetrahedron is a lower bound.

By the handshaking lemma, $\sum_{v \in V} deg(v) = 2 |E| = 12$. This is immediately fulfilled by $4$ joints.  Therefore, a tetrahedron is an upper bound as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer :)) But I know virtually no graph theory, so I will try to read the relevant bits and try to understand what you say here. But if there is a way to see this without using graph theory, that would be nice too.

Comment: Why is $|E|=6$? If a line has three joints in it, then there are two edges, contained in that line.

Comment: @Aig Wouldn't this violate non co-planarity, that no set of three lines exist in the same plane? Even if not this case can be checked quickly by hand.

Comment: I think, by definition, at each joint at least 3 non-co-planar lines must intersect. If there is a line with three joints on it, wouldn't that mean we need at least 7 lines?

Comment: @frelg I agree with your reasoning. I think this is the essential part of the solution and should be added to the answer. (I don’t see how non-co-planarity helps here, btw.)

Answer (score 3):

Note that $2$ intersecting lines define  a plane. Thus, a joint is formed by $3$ intersecting planes. Let's add one more plane to these three. Note that $4$ planes have at most $6$ distinct lines as intersections so $4$ is the minimum number of planes to contain $6$ intersecting lines that satisfy the requirement that no three of them are co-planar. Finally, there are $4$ ways to pick $3$ planes out of the set of $4$ so we can have at most $4$ joints. Tetrahedron is the shape with $4$ planes and $6$ lines.